# Angular AJAX call, how to get the parameters I have passed in from the success callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I would like to use a parameter that I have passed into an ajax call from the success method. Is it possible to do so? Here is my code

```
    for (var int = 0; int < intervalCount; int ++){

        var dateStart = '2014-04-27T' + intervalStartDump[int] + ':00';
        var dateEnd = '2014-04-27T' + intervalEndDump[int] + ':00';

        var parms = new Object();
        parms.StartDateTime = dateStart;
        parms.EndDateTime = dateEnd;

        //initiate all the sampling
        $http.post("/myApp/analytics/getAnalytics", parms)
            .success(function(data){
                if (data.RowsReturned == 0){
                    //no data to display
                }else{
                    if (!data.Error) {
                        var chartData = new Object();

                        chartData.date = parms.StartDateTime + " - " + parms.EndDateTime
                        chartData.result = data.Result;                           
                    }
                }
            }).error(function(data) {

            });
   }
```

Its a for loop that runs multiple ajax calls which has different start and end time as parameters. Since these calls return multiple sets of records at different timing, I would like to organise the results in an array of objects that has the start and end date time as one of their attributes.

**UPDATED ANSWER**
AngularJS supplies 4 returned objects in the success function

```
        var dateStart = '2014-04-27T' + intervalStartDump[int] + ':00';
        var dateEnd = '2014-04-27T' + intervalEndDump[int] + ':00';

        var parms = new Object();
        parms.StartDateTime = dateStart;
        parms.EndDateTime = dateEnd;

        $http.post("/myApp/analytics/getAnalytics", parms)
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config)
            {
                var dateStartInMySuccessFunction = config.data.StartDateTime;
                var dateEndInMySuccessFunction = config.data.StartDateTime;
            }
```

To get the parameters that one has passed in from the success callback , we need to use the config object's "data" object. Which is accessible quite easily. Refer to my code above. Hope this will help someone out there who is lazy to check the documentation like me till I am about to pee in my pants.

Comment: Anything you need to do with `chartData` should be done in the success function (or functions called by the success function).

Comment: No, its not a duplicate of the "callback function question" in the ajax call but to use a passed in parameter (parms.StartDateTime or parms.EndDateTime) in the success method.

Comment: I am getting undefine(s) in this line **chartData.date = parms.StartDateTime + " -" + parms.EndDateTime** because "it had forgotten" the parms Object in the success method. How do I pass the parms in in AngularJS?

Comment: The second parameter to [`$http.post`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post) is data to send to the server, but it looks like it is in scope anyway and should be accessible in the success function by closure.   I don't see a place to add data to send to the success function.  You could ping-pong it back in a server response, of course.

Comment: =(, need to find a way to do it in the database level =(((

Comment: `chartData` is local to the success function and is only defined for the limited duration of the success function.  So if you check `chartData` later in the console, it will be undef. If you are getting console errors for those lines when the ajax executes the success function, that suggests checking dateStart and dateEnd.

Comment: OK! I am going to answer my own question. Basically angular returns a config object on its success method $http.post("/myApp/analytics/getAnalytics", parms).success(function(data, status, headers, config). The config consists of a few variables and "data" is one of the objects that store my passed in parameters. So to get them from the success method, I just need to use this config.data.EndDateTime and config.data.StartDateTime. TADAH! Thanks @Paul

Comment: If it works, go for it.  Someone may find it useful.